# connect to mysql which is installed in another directory via python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I can connect to mysql using this command:

```
~/home/sama/myproject/build/build-debug/bin/mysql --user root -p -P 3305 -h 127.0.0.1
```

as my sql is not in /usr/local/bin how can I connect to mysql in python I have tried this but it did not work:

```
import mysql.connector
db =  mysql.connector.connect(host="127.0.0.1",   
                 user="root",         
                 password="",
                 port=3305)   
print(db)
```

how can I deal with it and connect to mysql in that directory via python?